# Get deleted object in Django DeleteView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to show an info message after deleting an object from a database. I decided to use SuccessMessageMixin for that purpose. How I can add object attributes to the success_message?

```
class PostDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
   model = Post
   success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

   def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
       return 'The ' + str(self.object) + ' post was deleted'
```

I thought I can do it that way. But there is no message after the deletion.

Comment: Can you share how your `Post` looks like? Especially the `__str__` part is essential.

Comment: `def __str__(self):
        return self.title`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`SuccessMessageMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.views.SuccessMessageMixin) only runs when a form is valid, so when the view inherits from a [**`FormView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView), or as specified in the documentation:

> Adds a success message attribute **to `FormView` based** classes.

You can not use this with a `DeleteView`, since a `DeleteView` does not use a `FormView` (or uses a `FormMixin`).

You can however make your own mixin, and use this for all `DeleteView`s based on the [implementation of the `SuccessMessageMixin` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1.7/django/contrib/messages/views.py):

```
from django.contrib import messages

class SuccessDeleteMessageMixin:
    success_message = ''

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        success_message = self.get_success_message()
        if success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, success_message)
        return response

    def get_success_message(self):
        return self.success_message
```

and then use this mixin with:

```
class PostDeleteView(SuccessDeleteMessageMixin, DeleteView):
   model = Post
   success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

   def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
       return f'The post {self.object} was deleted'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it explains why even logging did not work inside of the get_success_message

Comment: @ru_bender: well the logic was never "triggered", so indeed logging will not work then.